# ボタンのhidden変更について

Tags: objective-c, iphone

現在、ボタン２をAttributesInspectorでHiddenにチェックをつけ使えないようにしています、これをナビゲーションバーに設置したボタン１を押すとボタン２がHidden = NOになり、ボタン２が使える状態にしたいです。

コードは

ViewController.m

```
#import "CollectionHeaderView.h"

- (void)willTrash:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    //削除ボタンを表示Hidden = NOに
    CollectionHeaderView *collectionView = [[CollectionHeaderView
alloc] init];
    [collectionView sectionCanSee];
}
```

CollectionHeaderView.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *tappedSectionDelete;
```

CollectionHeaderView.m

```
- (void)sectionCanSee
{
    NSLog(@"ここは実行される");
    self.tappedSectionDelete.hidden = NO;
}
```

これで実行してもうまくいきません。
どなたか宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cannot be connected to repeating content`エラーについて。
`UICollectionView`の`Section Header`はセクションごとに１つ作られる、つまり複数存在する可能性があります。なので、ストーリーボードで`Outlet`に設定しようとしても、いっぱいある`Section Header`のうち、どれを指しているのか判断できないため、エラーになるのだと思います。

さて、解決方法について。
`Section Header`は`UICollectionViewDataSource`の
`collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:`で作られますので、この機会を利用してはいかがでしょうか？

```
///セクションヘッダーを作って返す
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
           viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                                 atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionHeaderView *view = 
      [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind
                                         withReuseIdentifier:"ストーリーボードで設定したIdentifier"
                                                forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (self.isButton1Pressed == YES) {
        view.button2.hidden = NO;
    }

    return view;
}

/// ボタン1が押されると実行される
- (IBAction)button1Pressed:(id)sender
{
    self.isButton1Pressed = YES;
    [self.collectionView reloadData]; //もう一度collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:を実行したいので
}
```

Comment: 回答していただきありがとうございます。お聞きしたいのですがself.isButton1Pressed = YES;のisButton1Pressedはどのように実装(宣言)すればいいでしょうか。

Comment: `UICollectionViewDataSource`に批准しているクラスで`@property (nonatomic) BOOL isButton1Pressed;`としてください。（nonatomicはお好みで）

Comment: ありがとうございます。思っていたようにに動くようになりました。本当にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

<strike>コードの一部しか載っていないのでだいぶ推測が混じってしまいますが、

おそらく`CollectionHeaderView`を`Storyboard`上に配置（あるいは`viewDidLoad`とかで追加）しているのだろうという前提で記載します。</strike>

`ViewController`上に配置した`View`の状態を変えるにはその`View`のインスタンスに対して処理を実行してあげる必要があります。

なので、`ViewController`の処理をこんな感じに変更してみてください。

```
#import "CollectionHeaderView.h"

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CollectionHeaderView *collectionView;

- (void)willTrash:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    //削除ボタンを表示Hidden = NOに
    [collectionView sectionCanSee];
}
```

`viewDidLoad`で追加しているのであれば

```
#import "CollectionHeaderView.h"

@implementation ViewController
{
    CollectionHeaderView *collectionView_;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    collectionView_ = [[CollectionHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:xx];
    [self.view addSubview:collectionView_];
}

- (void)willTrash:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    //削除ボタンを表示Hidden = NOに
    [collectionView_ sectionCanSee];
}
```

**----- コメントに対しての追記 -----**

追加情報ありがとうございます。
また、返信が遅くなってしまい申し訳有りません。

[UICollectionView: How to get the header view for a section?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13394282/uicollectionview-how-to-get-the-header-view-for-a-section)
これが最適解かは分かりませんが上記を参考にしてそれっぽい動作ができました。

ViewController.m（一部抜粋）

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    // ヘッダー格納用
    NSMutableDictionary* headers_;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // カスタムビューを登録
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"CollectionHeaderView" bundle:nil];
    [_collectionView registerNib:nib forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header"];
    // Dictionaryの初期化
    headers_ = [NSMutableDictionary new];
}

- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
           viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                                 atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
        CollectionHeaderView* header = [_collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"header" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        // Dictonaryに追加 ※とりあえずkeyはindexPathにしています。
        [headers_ setObject:header forKey:indexPath];
        return header;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didEndDisplayingSupplementaryView:(UICollectionReusableView *)view
      forElementOfKind:(NSString *)elementKind
           atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // 画面外に出たセクションを削除
    [headers_ removeObjectForKey:indexPath];
}

/**
 ナビゲーションバーのボタン押下時の処理
 */
- (IBAction)tapped:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    // Dictionaryから対象のViewを取得 ※とりあえず先頭
    NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    CollectionHeaderView* header = headers_[indexPath];
    // 削除ボタンを表示する
    [header sectionCanSee];
}
```

Comment: 情報が貧弱で申し訳ありません。CollectionHeaderViewは他クラスで作ってありStoryboardのコレクションビューのヘッダーセクションとして使っています。本当はViewController.mにアウトレット接続で名前をつけられたらいいのですが、そしたら”cannot be connected to repeating content”とエラーが出てきてしまいます。

Comment: @h_got いただいたコメントを基に回答に追記をしました。